# insert data from array to DB

Tags: php, mysql

I know that this theme is very common, but i'm stuck and can't find an error.

I created an array in PHP:

```
$dataarray=array("FECHAS" => date("Y-m-d"),"HORAS" => date("H:i:s"),
             "RGD" => 0,"RGA" => 0,"FLU" => 0,"DD2" => 0,
             "H2O" => 0,"PRES:U" => 0,"U" => 0,"V" => 0,"TS" => 0,
             "T1" => 0,"T2" => 0,"H1" => 0,"H2" => 0, "HS" => 0,
             "VV1" => 0,"VV2" => 0);
```

and i've got a table in MYSQL with the same names, but when i try to put data into it, it does nothing.

```
for($j=0;$j<$variable_para_base;$j++)
{
    $keys;
    $vars;
foreach($dataarray[$j] as $k=>$v)
{
    $keys.= $k.',';
    $vars.= $v.",";
}
echo $keys."<br>";
echo $vars."<br>";
mysqli_query($mysqli,'INSERT INTO ff ( .$keys.) VALUES ( .vars. ) ') or die(mysql_error());

unset($keys);
unset($vars);
}
```

if i do it with die option it does for only once another way my key starts to have strange values in the end of it.
Any ideas, and again sorry for maybe a repeted question. I get access to DB because it doesn't give me any error, though noow i'm doubting :(.

Comment: You're using mysqli and trying to call mysql_error(). http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php Has a full example of running queries and catching errors.

Comment: `or die()` is **bad**. Try using proper error handling. When you do something unexpected, you shouldn't die, right? read this: [Or die must die](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die)

Comment: @MikeB thanks didn't notice it, i'll check the link.

Comment: @Tikkes that explains why it used to cancel the uploading into db, will check Mikes link. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your end result might look something like this:

```
<?
for($j=0;$j<$variable_para_base;$j++)
{
    $keys = array();
    $vars = array();
    foreach($dataarray[$j] as $k=>$v)
    {
        $keys[] = $k;
        $vars[] = $v;
    }

    $placeholders = array_fill(0, count($keys), '?'); //used to fill a number of '?' needed to fill later

    //here we use the '?' array to be placeholders for the values
    $query = "INSERT INTO ff (".implode(', ', $keys).") VALUES (".implode(', ', $placeholders).")"; //implode the arrays and separate by comma

    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query); 

    $types  = array(str_repeat('s', count($vars))); //get the number of parameters and put the 's' to it (used for string values)
    $values = array_merge($types, $vars); //merge the arrays (gets you {'s', $value})

    call_user_func_array(array($statement, 'bind_param'), $values); //bind the values to the statement 

    $result = $statement->execute(); //execute.

    if($result) {
        print "Array inserted, worked like a charm.";
    }
    else {
        print "I failed, sorry...". $mysqli->error();
    }

    unset($keys);
    unset($vars);
}
$statement->close();
?>
```

This is however untested so test it good.

References you can use:

[Stackoverflow question: PHP - MySQL prepared statement to INSERT an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665981/php-mysql-prepared-statement-to-insert-an-array)

[Stackoverflow question: Best way to INSERT many values in mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149157/best-way-to-insert-many-values-in-mysqli)

[Stackoverflow question: Mysqli insert command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487696/php-mysqli-insert-command)

Comment: Still havent finished with all your suggestion but thanks a lot.

Comment: still having problems. I followed your code and changed 
      $placeholders = array_fill(0, count($keys), $vars);
      echo "<br>".$placeholders[1][0].$placeholders[1][1]." ".$placeholders[1][2]." ".$placeholders[1][3]."...".$placeholders[1][17];
with this i could check the data is correct, but it gives me:

Notice: Array to string conversion in: 
      $query = "INSERT INTO var (".implode(', ', $keys).") VALUES (".implode(', ', $placeholders).")";

and warning in: 
        call_user_func_array(array($statement, ' '), $values);

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax promlems in your query.

`INSERT INTO ff ( .$keys.) VALUES ( .vars. ) '` 
change it to

`INSERT INTO ff ( '.$keys.') VALUES ( '.$vars.') '`

Also you need to add `'` to the varialbles inserted as VALUES.

like that:
`$vars.= "'".$v."',";`

In addition your last variable is also ending with `,` and it shouldn't be.

Comment: This is a good solution. Just a hit: try and find stuff about prepared statements and use that instead. It will be much easier to use and is just better overall.

Comment: I currently still a mysql user :).. But I'll get to it evantually. thx!

Comment: I had already tried the same before but it didn't really work for me. As you said i did few mistakes with how i put in my data into the db. Still thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can not insert a array directly to mysql as mysql doesn't understand php data types. Mysql only understands SQL. So to insert this array into a mysql database you have to convert it to an sql statement. This can be done manually or by a library. The output should be an INSERT statement.

Here is a standard mysql insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ....) VALUES (VALUE1, VALUE2..)
```

If you have a table with name fbdata with the columns which are presented in the keys of your array you can insert with this small snippet. Here is how your array is converted to this statement.

```
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($insData));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($insData));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `fbdata`($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

Comment: MySql is deprecated, he - as he should - uses mysqli. This does not require "mysql_real_escape_string". Also, don't put variables into your strings. it is just bad.

Comment: You're still mixing db libraries

Comment: By the way, this is not an answer you did yourself. Don't copy-paste answers and get the credit. [Full answer here but bear in mind that this is old and deprecated for some part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054633/insert-array-into-mysql-database-with-php)

Comment: @Tikkes Oh wow.. that's downvote worthy. I'm going back through his answers and finding others.

Comment: will check @Tikkes link to see that example.

Answer (score 0):

you have error in query try this,

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,'INSERT INTO ff (' .$keys. ') VALUES (' .$vars. ') ') or die(mysql_error());
```